# Patching built-in method or class

Tags: python, mocking, built-in

I would like to find all instances in the code where np.random.seed is called (without using grep). In order to set a breakpoint in ipdb, I tried to find the source file with

```
import inspect; inspect.getsourcefile(np.random.seed)
```

but it throws a TypeError because it is a built-in method (because it is coded in C).

Is it possible to watch any calls to np.random.seed by modifying something in the main source file?
Additionally, it would be suitable to patch this method, e.g. additionally logging it (or calling a debugger):

```
def new_random_seed(seed):
    """
    This method should be called instead whenever np.random.seed 
    is called in any module that is invoked during the execution of 
    the main script
    """
    print("Called with seed {}".format(seed))
    #or: import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    return np.random.seed()
```

Maybe using a mock framework is the way to go?

The second question concerns the scenario in which a class B inherits from a class A in a library and I want to use the functionality of class B, but overwrite a function it uses from class A without modifying classes A and B. Probably, I should use mocking, but I am not sure about the overhead, so I wrote the following:

```
#in library
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def work(self):
        print("{} working".format(self.name))

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A("Machine")
    def run_task(self):
        self.A.work()

# in main script
# Cannot change classes A and B, so make a subclass C
import types
class C(B):
    def __init__(self, modified_work):
        super().__init__()
        self.A.work = types.MethodType(modified_work, self.A) #MethodType for self

b = B()
b.run_task()
modified_work = lambda self: print("{} working faster".format(self.name))
c = C(modified_work)
c.run_task()
```

The output is:

```
Machine working
Machine working faster
```

Is this good style?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simpler solution to your second question:

```
# lib.py
class A():
    def work(self):
        print('working')

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
    def run(self):
        self.a.work()
```

Then in your code:

```
import lib

class A(lib.A):
    def work(self):
        print('hardly working')

lib.A = A

b = lib.B()
b.run()
```

Or:

```
import lib

class AA(lib.A):
    def work(self):
        print('hardly working')

class BB(lib.B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = AA()

b = lib.B()
b.run()
b = BB()
b.run()
```